# What is the difference between code analysis and sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis, fxcop

I have a set of rules defined for Visual Studio Code Analysis and I also configured them in Sonar (http://www.sonarqube.org/). I get different results.

Why?

Code Analysis uses FxCop ? In Sonar I can configure FxCop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason is simple: these are different tools, with different features and capabilities...

In SonarQube, you can configure the quality profile (= rule set) that you want to apply on your project when you analyse it. This rule set is probably very different from the one available in Visual Studio Code Analysis.

Comment: Code Analysis uses FxCop ? In Sonar I can configure FxCop.

Comment: You can also use Microsoft FxCop rules together with the Sonar rules